# Unexplained and intermittent gap above text

Tags: inkscape

I'm getting intermittent gaps when working with text. In this example, notice the white line that cuts off the text:

[image: text on the layer]

[image: text bar]

Sometimes, cycling the window's size fixes it. Sometimes, it doesn't. <s>Exporting doesn't replicate the gap, however.</s>

I'm on 1.0.1. Currently, Inkscape is using 205MB of memory.

**Edit #1**

I just printed a sample, the text isn't in italics. I wonder if the speudo italics applied isn't the issue? The font doesn't have a formal italics specified.